# show values entered in form as a table before getting submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

First, I do not have much talent in ajax so please consider that while answering. Here I want to get all the values which I inserted into the form in a table before getting submitted but unfortunately am not getting the results I want. So far I have done this. Please have a look.

```
 <script>
 var form_data={ agent_name: $('#agent_name').val(),
                    type: $('input[name="type"]').val(),
                    number: $('#number').val(),
                    quantity: $('#quantity').val()
                  }

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/ajax_data',
    data: form_data,
    dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
    success: function(data){ 
        if(data){
            var len = data.length;
            alert(len);
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    if(data[i].agent_name && data[i].type){
                        txt += $('#table').append('<tr class="item-row"><td><input type="hidden" id="add_type" name="add_type[]" value="super">Super</td><td><input type="hidden" id="add_amount" name="add_amount[]" value="10">745</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_quantity" id="add_quantity" name="add_quantity[]" value="10">10</td><td name="add_amount" id="add_amount">100</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="add_checkbox" name="layout" id="add_checkbox" value="1" checked></td></tr>');

                    }
                }
                if(txt != ""){

                    $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
</script>
```

Here I want to pass the values of form_data in to the table I had written and how can we pass that and did it compulsory to use the `url` in ajax while using this am getting an error like `error: parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Here is my controller

```
public function ajax_data()
{
  $array = array("agent_name" => "admin","number"=>"785","type"=>"super","quantity"=>"10");
  $data['json'] = $array;
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: The `url` property in you `$.ajax()` call is a blank. This will cause the page itself to be called. Clearly, the page does not contain JSON style data, so the error you are getting is plausible. In order for your Ajax call to work you will need to direct it at a server based script that actually returns JSON data, i. e. enter its URL into the above mentioned property. Another issue will also be you table filling method. You are filling it with constant values and not using the data object you would be receiving from you server script.

Comment: @cars10m can you please refer any example

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax post will call the controller method for post values. The ajax code usually correct but you have not defined url.

```
 url: '',
```

Firstly define a method (ex: HomeController) then set ajax url parameter like

`url: '@Url.Action("Save","Home")'` or  `url: 'Save/Home'`

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Save(string agent_name, string type , int number,int quantity)
  {
    // return json
  }
```

**Note** :

> The data types you send from the form with the method types must be
>   the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to give you some hints to work on: The Ajax call could look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'echodata.php',
  data: form_data,
  dataType:"json", 
  success: function(data){
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>'+data.agent_name+'</td>' // + more columns ...
        +'</tr>');}
);
```

The php script should *really* be something that processes the incoming information (passed as the `$_POST` array) into some other data that will ultimately be echoed as JSON string.

This is just a trivial version of echodata.php for testing:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

**EDIT**:

While you have fixed your URL attribute and have added a "controller" on the server your Ajax success function still expects something it will not get. Your PHP script delivers a JSON string that will be parsed into as a JavaScript **object** and **not** an **array**. The object will not have the `length` property your success function tries to use. Instead you should be looking for the `json` property.

So, there is no point for the `for` loop, instead you can use `data.json.agent_name, data.json.number` and `data.json.type` (etc.) properties directly. Your current `.append()` also only adds a static string to your table. This should of course be changed to use the freshly received values.

Comment: thanks for spending time for me,now i had changed my code please have a look and while using your code am getting the same error like `error: parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Comment: why its calling undefined in place of values